# Missing type specifier, compiler changing Class* to int*

Tags: c++, class

I am working on this game and I am making each state a singleton. I am getting a lot of errors with the GetInstance function of SandboxState.

Here are the errors:

Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users\username\desktop\peggleclone\maze\maze\sandboxstate.cpp    5

Error   2   error C2248: 'SandboxState::SandboxState' : cannot access private member declared in class 'SandboxState'   c:\users\username\desktop\peggleclone\maze\maze\sandboxstate.cpp    5

Error   3   error C2248: 'SandboxState::~SandboxState' : cannot access private member declared in class 'SandboxState'  c:\users\username\desktop\peggleclone\maze\maze\sandboxstate.cpp    5

Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\username\desktop\peggleclone\maze\maze\sandboxstate.cpp    6

Error   5   error C2556: 'int *SandboxState::GetInstance(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'SandboxState *SandboxState::GetInstance(void)'  c:\users\username\desktop\peggleclone\maze\maze\sandboxstate.cpp    6

Error   6   error C2371: 'SandboxState::GetInstance' : redefinition; different basic types  c:\users\username\desktop\peggleclone\maze\maze\sandboxstate.cpp    6

It seems like the program doesn't recognize the return value of GetInstance 
 as a SandboxState*. It keeps labeling it as an int. I'm not sure why it is trying to call the constructor/destructor  in errors 2 and 3.

Here is SandboxState.cpp, SandboxState.h, and BaseGameState.h

SandboxState.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SandboxState.h"


SandboxState* SandboxState::GetInstance(void)
{
    static SandboxState s_Instance;

    return &s_Instance;
}

void SandboxState::Enter()
{


}

void SandboxState::Exit()
{

}

bool SandboxState::Update(float elapsedTime)
{

}

void SandboxState::Render(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{

}
```

SandboxState.h

```
#pragma once

#include "BaseGameState.h"
class SandboxState :
public BaseGameState
{
public:

    /**********************************************************/
    // Singleton Accessor
    static SandboxState* GetInstance( void );



    /**********************************************************/
    // IGameState Interface:
    virtual void    Enter(void) override;   // load resources
    virtual void    Exit(void) override;    // unload resources

    virtual bool    Update(float elapsedTime) override; // handle input & update entites
    virtual void    Render(sf::RenderWindow* window) override;  // render entities / menu



private:
    /**********************************************************/
    // SINGLETON!
    SandboxState(void) = default;
    virtual ~SandboxState(void) = default;
    SandboxState(const SandboxState&) = delete;
    SandboxState& operator= (const SandboxState&) = delete;
```

}

BaseGameState.h

```
#pragma once
class BaseGameState
{
protected:
    /**********************************************************/
    // Virtual Destructor
    BaseGameState(void) = default;
    ~BaseGameState(void) = default;


public:
    /**********************************************************/
    // IGameState Interface:
    virtual void    Enter( void )               = 0;    // load resources
    virtual void    Exit ( void )               = 0;    // unload resources

    virtual bool    Update( float elapsedTime ) = 0;    // handle input & update entites
    virtual void    Render( sf::RenderWindow* window )  = 0;    // render entities / menu
};
```

Comment: As a general tip, don't try to fix errors other than `Error 1`, because, more often than not, the other errors are a manifestation of the first.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of your `SandboxState` class declaration. That should be the reason for the errors that you are seeing.

As a side note, in your `BaseGameState` class, there is a comment that says `// Virtual Destructor`; however, it is next to a constructor and neither the constructor nor the destructor is marked as `virtual`.